# How to Add folder in Minio bucket using c#?

Tags: minio

I am using **Minio .net client library**

my requirement is **how can i store my files in folder structure** like

ABC is Bucket, CMS is inner folder and CMS folder contains files so how can i achive this ?

amazon s3 doing same things using key value pair i.e ABC/CMS

EDIT:

How can i access files url in my .net project ?
Ex In ABC bucket i have abc.png file so how can i access image to display on HTML tag.

```
<img src="---any path---/abc.png">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution of my own question.

```
 var fileAsStreamData = file.OpenReadStream();
 var fileName = "cms/" + file.FileName;
 await _minioClient.PutObjectAsync("ASAP", objectName: fileName, data: fileAsStreamData, size: file.Length, contentType: file.ContentType);
```

*Note:where "/" indicating folder structure in minio.
Ex. A/B/C/D/any_file_name so its consider as a inner folder like B is a inner folder of A and C is a inner folder of B and so on.*

Answer (score 1):

Creating an object whose name ends with a "/" will create a folder. It is an empty object that simulates a directory. [link](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/2423)

I'd like to add that deleting the last object in a directory will **also delete your folder**. If you do not take that into account in your code, it might lead to bugs and malfunctioning.